# Extending the lock screen time

Tags: 14.04, lock-screen

When ever I lock the screen, immediately the screen goes blank without the lock screen being active for few seconds or minutes at least. Read some questions which arose regarding this, but couldn't get a clear idea.

Is there any possibilities of making this work? Or is the feature being totally removed?

Comment: I am trying to eliminate or extend that time but I can't find a way to do it... as soon as I lock the computer, the screen starts to dim slowly until it turns off. Is this the same problem you're trying to solve? Did you find a way around it?

Comment: @Lotif yep that's the same problem, nop couldn't find any. Seems like there's no such work around for this unfortunately.